# Why doesn't ssh record failed access in /var/log/btmp?

Tags: ssh, log, remote-access

I want to record ssh failed accesses. I know that I can use `/var/log/auth.log` but I rather want to use the command `lastb`. But when I execute `lastb`, it doesn't show any records from ssh failed access. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature! ;)

See [Ubuntu Bug #743858](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/743858). This was actually done on purpose, in order to close [Debian Bug #314956](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=314956).

While at the end of that Ubuntu bug report there is some discussion about re-enabling `/var/log/btmp` logging for sshd, it seems nothing has been done so far. You could try to bump it up if you like.